# AngularJS: Problem with dynamically generated $scope name that starts with digits in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to generate `$scope`s with dynamically generated **`$scope` name** from a randomly generated Firestore document id and use them in `ng-repeat` on separate `<div>` as shown below:

```
$scope.FZLHIFSz7dVkbxZHP7Rg.allReplyActions = array1;
$scope.ykDP9cH5YFXv0Ki7sRAs.allReplyActions = array2;

<div class="sent-msg" ng-repeat="replyAction in FZLHIFSz7dVkbxZHP7Rg.allReplyActions | 
    orderBy:['ActionDate'] track by replyAction.ActionID ">

<div class="sent-msg" ng-repeat="replyAction in ykDP9cH5YFXv0Ki7sRAs.allReplyActions | 
    orderBy:['ActionDate'] track by replyAction.ActionID ">
```

At first, all works well until I hit a random id that **starts with digits**, then the error below appears:

```
Syntax Error: Token 'cZAb4I5cAUKUKcarxG' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 4 of the 
expression [[16cZAb4I5cAUKUKcarxG].allReplyActions | orderBy:['ActionDate']] starting at 
[cZAb4I5cAUKUKcarxG].allReplyActions | orderBy:['ActionDate']].
```

As you can see, the initial digits `16` has been ignored by AngularJS and becomes `cZAb4I5cAUKUKcarxG`. Therefore, based on the advice of certain answers on stackoverflow, I tried to change it to the following:

```
$scope['16cZAb4I5cAUKUKcarxG'].allReplyActions = array3;

<div class="sent-msg" ng-repeat="replyAction in ['16cZAb4I5cAUKUKcarxG'].allReplyActions | 
    orderBy:['ActionDate'] track by replyAction.ActionID ">
```

Now the error has gone, but the data/messages can no longer be rendered by Angular's `ng-repeat` as before even though `['16cZAb4I5cAUKUKcarxG'].allReplyActions` contains data. It appears as HTML comment as shown below:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: replyAction in ['16cZAb4I5cAUKUKcarxG'].allReplyActions | 
   orderBy:['ActionDate'] track by replyAction.ActionID  -->
```

Below is how I dynamically generated the data binding and render the messages on the browser:

```
let tempChatHistory = $("#tempChatHistory").html();
let actionScope = angular.element($("#" + initAction.ActionID)).scope();

tempChatHistory = tempChatHistory.replace(/allReplyActions/g, "['" + initAction.ActionID + "'].allReplyActions");

console.log("tempChatHistory =", tempChatHistory);
actionScope["'" + initAction.ActionID + "'"] = {
   allReplyActions: await getReplyActions(initAction)
};

// It contains data!
console.log("actionScope.allReplyActions = ", actionScope["'" + initAction.ActionID + "'"].allReplyActions);

angular.element($chatWindow).append($compile(tempChatHistory)(actionScope));

actionScope.$apply();
```

Note that before adding that global replace with `['...']`, this logic works well when there is no numerical prefixes on that randomly generated ids. May I know what else that I've done wrong? Please enlighten me, thank you!

Comment: **NOTE:** I could try adding alphabetical prefix to the `$scope` name like this: `"thread" + initAction.ActionID`, but this will make the logic of other dependencies no longer as straight forward and become very complex. I'm trying to avoid this approach as much as I can and wish the `['...']` approach would work. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any control over your scope data structure? You might have an easier time reasoning about dynamic collections as an array instead of explicitly referenced object members. something along the lines of `$scope.chatHistory = [{id:'16cZAb4I5cAUKUKcarxG', allReplyActions:{...actions}}];`

Comment: Yes @MarkClark , I think your alternative should work too, coz my app requires the coexistence of multi instances of `chatHistory` by different `threads` on the same page. This is why I need to separate them by the **thread id** (aka. `initAction.ActionID`) via the `$scope` name for easy references and manipulations. Anyway, adding the `thread` prefix solved the problem too, although not so clean. All other better solutions are still welcome.

Comment: Similar to my previous suggestion, you may want to pass each chatHistory to its own component/directive. That way you only have to deal with an array in the parent template and not an array of arrays. By making this more compositional/componentized, you should end up with simpler templates.